# pyspark cache values in a spark worker

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching

I am writing a python library that will be called by a pyspark code.  As part of this library there is a slow function.

I would like to cache the results of this function so that a table is kept in memory.  (At least in each worker).

For example:

```
def slow_function(x):
   time.sleep(10)
   return x*2


class CacheSlowFunction():

   def __init__(self):
      self.values = {}

   def slow_function(x):
       if x in self.values:
          return self.values[x]
       else:
          res = slow_function(x)
          self.values[x] = res
          return res

def main(x):
   csf = CacheSlowFunction()
   s = 0
   for i in range(x):
     s += csf.slow_function(i)
   return s
```

and the code is called from spark with something like:

`map(main,  [i for i in range(10000)])`

Now the code will create a table (`self.values`) for each call.  Is it possible to have this table at least shared across computations done on the same worker?

Comment: I'd use a broadcast variable https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables to get the values once and supply them to all workers.

Comment: It depends how you want to use that table. Do you want to join it with another table? If so as @kberg suggested broadcsting it is the best option. First load the table into a dataframe then broadcast it when joining

Comment: as far as I understand the broadcast variable is read only.  Here the table starts as empty and needs to be filled in the worker.

Comment: In general this is not a good pattern for spark. If slow_function is CPU bound then I'd say you need to scale your task out. If slow_function is I/O bound then I think you need a different approach to your job. Perhaps reducing your data, perform your I/O bound tasks, then merge the results back in?

Without more context on the nature of slow_function it's hard to say. If you're attempting to optimize a spark job by using a standard caching pattern you're going to have a bad time.